# SVG to stretch at the biggest dimension and then fill the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a SVG that I want to use as a background for body.
What CSS should I use if I want my background to stretch at the biggest dimension and then fill the rest, like this:

- **Case 1:** If the browser's **viewwidth > viewheight**, to make svg take the height of viewport, keep the aspect ratio(it' s 1:1), and then repeat on the horizontal untill the body is fully covered.
- **Case 2:**  If the browser's **viewwidth < viewheight**(usually mobile version of a website), to make svg take the width of viewport, keep the aspect ratio(it' s 1:1), and then repeat on the vertical untill the body is fully covered.

I am trying to obtain this without JS, but if it's not possible, JS is a way to go too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need JS for the viewport comparisons but from there you can use [cover or contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) for the background-size prop.